# How to fetch the key value and apply the condition in keys of dictionary?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

[image]

in my project i want to fetch the key value from the dictionary along with the condition that if key value is Yes then tick image shown and if the key value is no then cross image shown. i am trying to get the key value but not getting the value.
please help me to solve this problem. i am sharing my snapshot n codes

```
NSDictionary *strName9 = [productDict objectForKey:@"hand_emb"];
```

inside StrName9 below dictionary i fetched

```
"hand_emb" =         {
            1 =             {
                key = lengha;
                value = yes;
            };
            2 =             {
                key = Pyjami;
                value = no;
            };
        };
```

now what to do after this please help me.

Comment: At first replace your statement with `NSDictionary *dict = [productDict objectForKey:@"hand_emb"];` and show your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are accessing is `NSDictionary` not `NSString` so replace it with following snippet which iterates through all the elements of `NSDictionary`.

**Objective C**

```
NSDictionary *dict = productDict[@"hand_emb"];
[dict enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(id key, id obj, BOOL *stop)
{
    if([obj isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
    {
        NSLog(@"key : %@",obj[@"key"]);
        NSLog(@"value : %@",obj[@"value"]);
        if([obj[@"value"] isEqualToString:@"yes"])
        {
            // *** Write code to show tick ***
        }
        else
        {
            // *** Write code to show cross ***
        }
    }
}];
```

**Swift**

```
var dict: [NSObject : AnyObject] = productDict["hand_emb"]
dict.enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock({(key: AnyObject, obj: AnyObject, stop: Bool) -> Void in
    if obj.isKindOfClass([NSObject : AnyObject]) {
        NSLog("key : %@", obj["key"])
        NSLog("value : %@", obj["value"])
        if (obj["value"] == "yes") {
            // *** Write code to show tick ***
        }
        else {
            // *** Write code to show cross ***
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: when i write your code this error is coming Incompatible block pointer types sending 'void (^)(__strong id)' to parameter of type 'void (^)(__strong id, __strong id, BOOL *)'

Comment: i have updated answer, as i am using newer version of xcode & iOS, its happening. or you can replace `enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock` with `for` loop.

Comment: i updated code in post, have you tried it, and i already instructed you to use for loop `for(id obj in dict)`if it doesn't work.

Comment: i am getting 'dict' is nil?

Comment: then there is something wrong with your `json` data. given code works with anything. figure out whats prob.

Comment: see sometimes the dict is nil then we have to show nil, sometimes inside it the dict is having like above which i provided, so if it is nil we have to show blank and if it is having key,value we have to show that key and value

Comment: then put a condition. stackoverflow is not about such discussion. before ask for something you should show what you have done as your effort.